# Zend Framework with MySQL "SELECT"

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I am using zend framework, and I need to add option "where", which include commas (") it is used for filtering, tried to use it in html:

```
<option value="&quot;msg&quot;:&quot;Paid&quot;"><?php echo Core_Locale::translate('Paid')?></option>
```

But after turning on other page filter disappear. What I need to get using this:

> {"success":true,"version":"1.0","paid":false,"added_to_balck_list":true,"msg":"Paid"}

I'm sure to get msg using fetchall and select each which is equal, but in table is tones of data and I won't use it. So guys may be you know **how I can add commas in "where"?**

```
$select->where( "response like '%$message%'");
```

In SQL, it should look like:

> response like "msg":"Paid"

But I can't just type like %paid% because every record have Paid:true of paid paid:false and I get all the records.

Comment: Why are you storing and attempting to search JSON in the database?

Comment: Because it's part of system. My question is only 1/10 of work, because i need to use keywords to display records in list.

Comment: Well i would just use a simple key like `paid` as the option value and then map that to what it means in terms of the query. like `$terms = array ('paid' => '"msg:"Paid"');` then you could access with `$terms[$_POST['response']]`. However you could just do `value="\"msg":\"Paid\""` on your element .